# Display Instagram captions in an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, instagram

Is there a way to display Instagram captions in an `iframe`?

The reason I am not using Instagram embed option is because I need to change dynamically the link of the popup which carries the frame.

```
<iframe class="popupInst" src="http://instagram.com/p/qbq6fIJMVZ/embed" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `/captioned/` to the end of your embed URL; like

> https://www.instagram.com/p/{shortcode}/embed/captioned/

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tool to generate iframe instagram embed: http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/embed#https://www.instagram.com/p/8_kRtJBsBq/

You can select `size` and `caption` option, which will automatically adjust the height and generate embed code.

[image]